# Not able to start logstasth after patching activity

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

After some patching activity on my server, now i am not able to run any of conf file below is the error I am new to it not able to resolve it:

```
 you might need to reinstall the gem which depends on the missing jar or in case there is Jars.lock then resolve the jars with `lock_jars` com
mand
no such file to load -- org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.6.2/log4j-core-2.6.2 (LoadError)
              do_require at /kibana/logstash-6.1.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/jar-dependencies-0.3.11/lib/jar_dependencies.rb:348
    block in require_jar at /kibana/logstash-6.1.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/jar-dependencies-0.3.11/lib/jar_dependencies.rb:255
  require_jar_with_block at /kibana/logstash-6.1.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/jar-dependencies-0.3.11/lib/jar_dependencies.rb:297
             require_jar at /kibana/logstash-6.1.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/jar-dependencies-0.3.11/lib/jar_dependencies.rb:254
             require_jar at /kibana/logstash-6.1.1/lib/bootstrap/patches/jar_dependencies.rb:6
                  <main> at /kibana/logstash-6.1.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash-core_jars.rb:18
                 require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:955
                  <main> at /kibana/logstash-6.1.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash-core/logstash-core.rb:1
                 require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:955
                  <main> at /kibana/logstash-6.1.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash-core/logstash-core.rb:8
                 require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:955
                  <main> at /kibana/logstash-6.1.1/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb:66
```

Comment: have you tried updating logstash?

Comment: What was the patch activity? It seems related to the Log4Shell vulnerability and it looks that the log4j jar was removed or replaced by a newer version. This will not work, You need to contact the person responsable for your server and direct them to this [elastic steps](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-5-0-0-6-8-20-and-7-0-0-7-16-0-log4j-cve-2021-44228-cve-2021-45046-remediation/292343) to remediate log4shell on that logstash version, just changing the version of log4j jar will not work and will break your logstash.